# Unknown origin of space between 2 div elements

Tags: html, css, spacing

There is a sizeable space between 2 div elements, div header and div content, in my php page, and I cannot figure out where it's coming from or why it's there.

HTML:

```
...
<div id="header">
HEADER
</div>
<div id="content">
  <h3>Login</h3>
  <form action="login.php" method="post">
...
```

CSS:

```
html {
height: 100%;
}

body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
border-style: none;
background: black;
}

#header {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
height: 15%;
width: 100%;
border-style: none;
background: #02F72F;
text-align: center;
}

#content {
margin-top: 0px;
padding: 0px;
height: 70%;
width: 100%;
border-style: none;
background: white;
text-align: center;
}
...
```

When implemented, there is a long black bar that separates the two divs visually. I know it's black because I specifically changed the background to black, but with the margins and padding set to 0, I don't know why there is a space to begin with. Do div elements have a default spacing and how can I override this?

Comment: Remove the height's 30 and 70 from the css and try again?

Comment: I don't believe it's an issue with the sizing, as when I change the sizes, the header does increase in size, but the black space moves with it, not decreasing or increasing the size of the space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enter a `float:left` for the two elements and the space will go away (between them - the remaining 15% will of course still be there):
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/ENGx9/

```
#header {
    float:left;
    ....
}

#content {
    float:left;
    ...
}
```

Optionally, the `h3` tag's margin pushes the div down - you can modify the tag like this instead to use padding to give the header some room:

```
h3 {
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 0;
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/ENGx9/1/

Comment: This does indeed resolve it, thank you. But, I noticed that if I enter any text between <div id="content"> and <h3>Login</h3>, it resolves it without the need for the float property. So, what changes the size of the header (or the content div?) between when I have text entered and when I don't? If there is no content/data entered between divs, are their spacing and placement interpreted as non existent?

Comment: It seem to be the h3's margin that pushes the div down. You can instead of float modify the h3 (I'll update my answer). When you enter text between the margin gets below the edge and can therefor not "push" anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You have given, `height: 15%;` for your header and `height: 100%;` for your body. so your header will occupy `15%` of the height of the body. So you see a space there for the corresponding `15%` height.